# How can I make custom character face editor In my game In an optimal way?

Tags: unity, shaderlab, vertex-shader

In many games there Is section as customize character that you can make your own character.I always love to know how can I make something like It.

Even old game have this feature? but how ?

[image: old game]

For Implementing It I need accurate separation for communating between values and facial parts size.
So first I made multiple height-map based on facial parts for modifying by vertex shader and work correctly but this method Isn't optimal.can I Implement It just by one texture?

[image: worked]
[image: first solution]

then I tried by using colorful mapping texture for detecting facial parts, but I have problem for getting color values from mapping texture In my shader code.

[image: Mortal Kombat]

mapping texture:

[image: face mapping]

My problem Is that my vertex shader Isn't match with my mapping texture.for example If I change `_NoseLength` other parts will changes.how can I tell to vertex shader which part is nose,forehead,lip,cheek,... In my colorful mapping.

Here Is my Shader Code:

```
Shader "Custom/Extrude" {
        Properties {
            _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
            _ModTex ("Vertex Modify", 2D) = "white" {}
            _NoseLength ("NoseLength ", Range(-0.05,0.01)) = 1.0
            _LipSize ("LipSize ",  Range(-0.05,0.01)) = 1.0
            _CheekBones ("CheekBones ", Range(-0.05,0.01)) = 1.0
            _ForeHead ("ForeHead ", Range(-0.05,0.01)) = 1.0
            _EyeSize("EyeSize", Range(-0.05,0.01)) = 1.0

        }
        SubShader {
            Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue" = "Transparent"}
            Cull off
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _ModTex;

            uniform fixed _NoseLength;
            uniform fixed _LipSize;
            uniform fixed _CheekBones;
            uniform fixed _ForeHead;
            uniform fixed _EyeSize;

            struct Input {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
            };

            void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
                float4 lipSize = tex2Dlod(_ModTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0)).g;//Green
                float4 nose = tex2Dlod(_ModTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0)).b; //Blue
                float4 eye = tex2Dlod(_ModTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0)).r; // Red
                float2 cheek = tex2Dlod(_ModTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0)).rg; // Yellow
                float2 forehead = tex2Dlod(_ModTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0)).rb; // Purple
                v.vertex.y += _LipSize * lipSize;
                v.vertex.y += _NoseLength * nose;
                v.vertex.y += _EyeSize * eye;
                v.vertex.y += _CheekBones * cheek;
                v.vertex.y += _ForeHead * forehead ;

            }

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
                half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
            }
            ENDCG
        } 
        FallBack "Diffuse"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's Implement It step by step:

1.First you need a way for accessing to color values In texture by shader.

2.Then you can modify vertex shader by color values In your colorful Height map.

**Step 1** : Accessing to colors In the texture test:

[image: accessing to colors In texture]

```
Shader "SmkGames/ColorReplacement"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _TH("Threshold value",Range(0,1)) = 0.5

        [HideInInspector]_Red("Filter Color 1", Color) = (1.0,0,0,1.0) //Red
        [HideInInspector]_Green("Filter Color 2", Color) = (0,1.0,0,1.0) //Green
        [HideInInspector]_Blue("Filter Color 3", Color) = (0,0,1.0,1.0) //Blue
        [HideInInspector]_Yellow("Filter Color 4", Color) = (1.0,1.0,0,1.0) //Yellow
        [HideInInspector]_Purple("Filter Color 5", Color) = (1.0,0,1.0,1.0) //Purple
        [HideInInspector]_Cyan("Filter Color 6", Color) = (0,1.0,1.0,1.0) //Cyan
        [HideInInspector]_White("Filter Color 7", Color) = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) //Cyan

        _ColorReplacement1("Red", Color) = (1.0,0,0,1.0) //Red
        _ColorReplacement2("Green", Color) = (0,1.0,0,1.0) //Green
        _ColorReplacement3("Blue", Color) = (0,0,1.0,1.0) //Blue
        _ColorReplacement4("Yellow", Color) = (1.0,1.0,0,1.0) //Yellow
        _ColorReplacement5("Purple", Color) = (1.0,0,1.0,1.0) //Purple
        _ColorReplacement6("Cyan", Color) = (0,1.0,1.0,1.0) //Cyan
        _ColorReplacement7("White", Color) = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) //White


    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;

            uniform float _TH; //Threshold value

            //MainColors
            uniform float4 _Red;
            uniform float4 _Green;
            uniform float4 _Blue;
            uniform float4 _Yellow;
            uniform float4 _Purple;
            uniform float4 _Cyan;
            uniform float4 _White;

            //Colors Replacement
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement1;
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement2;
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement3;
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement4;
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement5;
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement6;
            uniform float4 _ColorReplacement7;


            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };



            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : Color
            {
                fixed4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                if(distance(color,_Red)<=_TH){
                    return  _ColorReplacement1;
                }
                if(distance(color,_Green)<=_TH){
                    return  _ColorReplacement2;
                }
                if(distance(color,_Blue)<=_TH){
                    return _ColorReplacement3;
                }
                if(distance(color,_Yellow)<=_TH){
                    return  _ColorReplacement4;
                }
                if(distance(color,_Purple)<=_TH){
                    return _ColorReplacement5;
                }
                if(distance(color,_Cyan)<=_TH){
                    return _ColorReplacement6;
                }
                if(distance(color,_White)<=_TH){
                    return _ColorReplacement7;
                }
                return  float4(color.rgb,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: now you can easily modify vertex shader by color values In your colorful Height map:

[image: modifying vertex shader by color values]

```
    void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
    float4 FacialParts = tex2Dlod(_Mask, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0));

    if(distance(FacialParts,_FilterColor1)<=_TH){
    v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * _Width; // Extruding
    v.vertex.z +=  _Height * Intensity;
    }
}
```